# Sending PDF file from Salesforce to XERO, but it's not happening

Tags: rest-api, api, webservices, apexrest, blob

I want to send PDF file which is generated by VF page from Salesforce to XERO.

But I'm trying to send but it's not happening

XERO syntax, it receives like below format

```
POST /api.xro/2.0/Receipts/e59a2c7f-4078-a0f3-73537afcbba9/Attachments/Image00394.ddf
```

Here I'm not understanding how to pass PDF content in the URL above image00394 name.

Here is what I'm doing

```
    string pdfcon='asdasdasdasd';
Blob pdfBody = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(pdfcon);


String endpoinurl='callout:Xero_Integration/api.xro/2.0/Invoices/32b8b9-4b5-45da-84ba-80e1bb47881/Attachments/';

HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest();
// set endpoint destination
req.SetEndpoint(endpoinurl);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('xero-tenant-id','7bc01e1-d87-4a8b-9b96-2ffbc88f1cb8');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/pdf');
req.setBodyAsBlob(pdfBody);


Http http = new Http();
// send the request
HttpResponse response = http.send(req);

System.debug(response.getBody());
```

If I'm doing like below with filename mentioning in the URL, the PDF file is inserting but when I open it in XERO it showing below error:

[image]

```
  String endpoinurl='callout:Xero_Integration/api.xro/2.0/Invoices/322cb8b9-40b5-45da-84ba-80e1bb437881/Attachments/'+pdfBody+'.pdf';
```

Finally I'm not understanding how to pass PDF content in the ENDPOINT URL of Http callouts?

Comment: There's some issue in blobs with salesforce. I'd suggest to use content version(files) and instead of posting from salesforce to Xero, you can download at Xero directly(or pull through code/ CURL commands).

Comment: Thanks @YsrShk it's working

Answer (score 0):

Here is the coding what i used to solve that, I used contentversion object in salesforce.

```
    Attachment attach = [SELECT Id, Name, Body, ContentType, ParentId From Attachment LIMIT 1];

ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.Title = 'Test Document';
cv.PathOnClient = 'TestDocument.pdf';
cv.VersionData = attach.body;
//cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
  
String endpoinurl='callout:Xero_Integration/api.xro/2.0/Invoices/340b5-45-80e1bb481/Attachments/'+cv.PathOnClient

HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest();
req.SetEndpoint(endpoinurl);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('xero-tenant-id','7bc2-d087-2ffbc88f1cb8');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/pdf');
req.setBodyAsBlob(attach.body);

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
System.debug(response.getBody());
```

If it's useful to you vote it!...